# Control YouTube Video Speed Without Plugin

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, youtube

I am wondering if there is a way to control the speed on **ANY** video on YouTube **without using a plugin**.

Comment: If you could remove the two methods from your question and instead add them as a self-answer, that would be great. Remember to keep the question just a question, and with enough information for other people to answer it (i.e. don't add extra question information in the self-answers).

Comment: @Bob thanks! I took your suggestions.

Comment: If you have a managed switch/router you can setup QOS and limit speeds from that IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two methods (from [this](http://yatharthrock.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-speed-up-or-slow-down-playback.html) site), although neither are ideal:

---

*Does not work for all videos!*

**Method 1:** Go to http://www.youtube.com/html5 and request the HTML5 player.

---

*Works for all videos but is a hassle.*

**Method 2:** Copy the videoID and paste it after `v=` in the following link

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=&vq=large
```

Note: The videoID is the alphanumeric string after `v=` e.g., for `youtube.com/watch?v=KxICWhyO7dI&feature=autoplay`, it's `KxICWhyO7dI`.

Comment: I can't get method 2 to work. Did you try it with a video with adds (and in Chrome)? (they seem to be forced in Flash). Also... you might want to add **how** to slow the video down. It might not be apparent for everyone you need to click the gear icon. (i needed to look at your source-link to find it)